# Conditionally filling values in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following Dataframe :

```
temp = pd.DataFrame({
              'long_entry':[False,True,False,False],
              'long_exit':[False,False,False,True]
})


    long_entry  long_exit
0   False   False
1   True    False
2   False   False
3   False   True
```

I add 2 more columns with 0 that will receive conditional values :

```
temp['open_long']=0
temp['close_long']=0
temp['long']=0

long_entry  long_exit   open_long   close_long   long
0   False   False       0           0            0
1   True    False       0           0            0
2   False   False       0           0            0
3   False   True        0           0            0
```

What i am trying to do is to fill open_long, close_long and long according to the following conditions :

First row will be 0 for all 3 columns, then for the next ones:

- **open_long**: if previous row `long_entry == 0` and same row `long_entry` == `True` then `open_long = 1`, else `open_long = 0`
- **close_long**: if previous row `long` value equals `1` and same row `long_exit == True`, then `close_long = -1`, else `close_long= 0`
- **long**:  just equal to same row `open_long` + same row `close_long` + previous row long

the resulting Dataframe is :

```
long_entry  long_exit   open_long   close_long   long
0   False   False       0           0            0
1   True    False       1           0            1
2   False   False       0           0            1
3   False   True        0          -1            0
```

I was able to do it using loop but since I am working with 10 years of daily data it is taking a lot of time to complete. What is the optimal way to approach this problem in Python ?

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following, using `shift()` method.

```
temp['long_entry_lag'] = temp['long_entry'].shift(-1)
```

and the result will be:

```
 long_entry  long_exit long_entry_lag
 0       False      False           True
 1        True      False          False
 2       False      False          False
 3       False       True            NaN
```

And then you could do:

```
temp['open_long'] = (temp.long_entry - temp.long_entry_lag) == -1
```

and so on. These vectorized operations should be very fast on large datasets.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that open_long and close_long are dependent on a recalculated long on each row. I am not being able to replicate the resulting dataframe using shift. Were you ?

Comment: I was researching and i think it has to be something equivalent of the `rapply` function in R.  "rapply stands for recursive apply, and as the name suggests it is used to apply a function to all elements of a list recursively "